# Are cross origin requests still not allowed for chrome browser extensions that are hosted?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest in chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions/9422216#9422216)

I found this post when searching the site for my problem, but is this information still valid? Are cross origin requests still not allowed for chrome browser extensions that are hosted remotely?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, as there is no permission for requesting cross domain access.](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#offline)

The way I think of it is that packaged apps are like extensions that happen to have an app icon instead of a browser or page action, and hosted apps are merely glorified bookmarks with some special properties. Only extensions can request access for cross domain requests.