# XMLHttpRequest is not defined, in a chrome extension options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make an XMLHttpRequest in the options page of an extension. In my `options.js` file I simply have the following code :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        var xhr = new getXMLHttpRequest();
}
```

But I have this error in the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getXMLHttpRequest is not defined

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions) that getXMLHttpRequests are a problem for *hosted apps*, but in this case, it's a simple *extension*, so I don't understand.

Comment: I got the error "XMLHttpRequest is not defined" in `background.js`, for a different reason -- because Chrome extensions with Manifest v3 [use a service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#service-workers) instead of a background page or background script, and [XMLHttpRequest is not available in service workers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393563/3345375). Thus it's necessary to use the Fetch API instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To construct an XHR object you use `new XMLHttpRequest();`.

`getXMLHttpRequest` is not a standard function.

> I saw here that getXMLHttpRequests are a problem…

The question at the other end of the link doesn't use a function with a name starting with *get*.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{ 
    var objXMLHttp=null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return objXMLHttp;
}
```