# Service Worker and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, service-worker

I am trying to use AJAX to retrieve the details for the push notification I want to display on the users end, but it doesn't work yet.

```
/*
*
*  Push Notifications codelab
*  Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
*
*  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
*  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
*  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
*  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
*  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or     implied.
*  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
*  limitations under the License
*
*/

 // Version 0.1

//'use strict';

console.log('Started', self);

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Installed', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Activated', event);
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);

    var title = 'Push message';
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.domain.nl/devtest/1.php", false);
    xhttp.send();
    title = xhttp.responseText;

    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data, {
            'body': 'The Message',
            'icon': 'images/icon.png'
        })
    );
});
```

When I use GCM to send a push notification to the client, Chrome gives this error on the service worker:

**sw.js:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest within service worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112425/xmlhttprequest-within-service-worker)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` has been deprecated and it's not available in the Service Worker scope. Instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, you can use the [`Fetch API`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch).

Comment: They seriously removed regular ajax from the service worker? WTF? Looks like I wont be using it for a long time.

Comment: @MichaelHanon, Yea its true, fetch is the only way. also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727718/632951

Comment: https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/xmlhttprequest-is-no-longer-available-in-service-workers/

Comment: Fetch API fails with self signed SSL on localhost (lol)

Answer (score 6):

To do this we can set the method and body parameters in the fetch() options.

```
 fetch(url, {  
    method: 'post',  
    headers: {  
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
    },  
    body: 'foo=bar&lorem=ipsum'  
  })
  .then(json)  
  .then(function (data) {  
   console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);  
  })  
  .catch(function (error) {  
    console.log('Request failed', error);  
  });
```

Should you want to make a fetch request with credentials such as cookies, you should set the credentials of the request to "include".

```
fetch(url, {  
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a bearer token similar to the Ajax where you can add this
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + apiAuthToken);
        },