# Workbox 6 cache a json file

Tags: json, workbox

Workbox 6. I am trying to add a json file to service worker cache storage but failing.  Any suggestions gratefully received.
Using code from the docs I can cache all my other file types.

I have tried to pick up the specific file, but get the error
NetworkFirst.js:115 Uncaught (in promise) no-response: no-response ::

```
[{"url":"https://jnchapman.tk/index.html"}]
    at Object._handle (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-strategies.prod.js:1:5425)
    at async Object.Wt (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-strategies.prod.js:1:3926)
```

code to cache .json file

```
  workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://jnchapman.tk/results_202104_003.json',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'json',
  })
);
```

whole sw.js file

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */
/* https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw */
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-sw.js');


const { registerRoute } = workbox.routing;
const { CacheFirst } = workbox.strategies;
const { CacheableResponse } = workbox.cacheableResponse;
const { ExpirationPlugin } = workbox.expiration;
const { warmStrategyCache } = workbox.strategies;
//const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = workbox.strategies;

// This can be any strategy, CacheFirst used as an example.

/*
const strategy = new CacheFirst();
const urls = [
  '/offline.html'
];


warmStrategyCache({ urls, strategy });

offlineFallback();
*/

const HTML_CACHE = "html";
const JS_CACHE = "javascript";
const STYLE_CACHE = "stylesheets";
const IMAGE_CACHE = "images";
const FONT_CACHE = "fonts";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'document',
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: HTML_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 10,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'script',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: JS_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'style',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: STYLE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'image',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: IMAGE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'font',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: FONT_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);


// Cache the Google Fonts stylesheets with a stale-while-revalidate strategy.
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://jnchapman.tk/results_202104_003.json',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'json',
  })
);

// Cache .json file
/*
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === 'https://jnchapman.tk/results_202104_003.json',
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'json',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);
*/


/*
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
  /\.(?:json)$/,
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'HTML_CACHE2',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 1,
        maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
      }),
    ],
  })
);
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution A**

I have found a work around to the problem by precaching the .json file
However, a better solution without precaching would be appreciated.

I generated the precache using the workbox wizard.

```
const { precacheAndRoute } = workbox.precaching;

precacheAndRoute([{url:"results_202104_003.json",revision:"091fb3fb63a405c4130126aff653eaec"}]);
```

I also added code to display an offline page

```
const strategy = new CacheFirst();
const urls = [
  '/offline.html'
];


warmStrategyCache({ urls, strategy });

offlineFallback();
```

Summary

The full workaround is here.  This is for a simple website of a few html pages that never change name so use cache using NetworkFirst.  There is no routing code. All other content has unique file names which change when the content is updated, so cache using StaleWhileRevalidate. The offline.html page is also effectively precached.

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */
/* https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw */
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-sw.js');


const { registerRoute } = workbox.routing;
const { CacheFirst } = workbox.strategies;
const { CacheableResponse } = workbox.cacheableResponse;
const { ExpirationPlugin } = workbox.expiration;
const { warmStrategyCache } = workbox.recipes;
const { offlineFallback } = workbox.recipes;
//const { cacheFirst} = workbox.cacheFirst;
//const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = workbox.strategies;

// This can be any strategy, CacheFirst used as an example.

const { precacheAndRoute } = workbox.precaching;

precacheAndRoute([{url:"results_202104_003.json",revision:"091fb3fb63a405c4130126aff653eaec"}]);


const strategy = new CacheFirst();
const urls = [
  '/offline.html'
];


warmStrategyCache({ urls, strategy });

offlineFallback();


const HTML_CACHE = "html";
const JS_CACHE = "javascript";
const STYLE_CACHE = "stylesheets";
const IMAGE_CACHE = "images";
const FONT_CACHE = "fonts";
const JSON_CACHE = "json";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'document',
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: HTML_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 10,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'script',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: JS_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'style',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: STYLE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'image',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: IMAGE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'font',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: FONT_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'json',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: JSON_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

**Solution B**

I realised that Ajax not covered by Service Workers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393563/267706

"XMLHttpRequest has been deprecated and it's not available in the Service Worker scope. Instead of XMLHttpRequest, you can use the Fetch API."

Swapped over to using Fetch to load the .json file

Now the following works.
Any .json file on my webiste gets cached.

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */
/* https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw */
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-sw.js');


const { registerRoute } = workbox.routing;
const { CacheFirst } = workbox.strategies;
const { CacheableResponse } = workbox.cacheableResponse;
const { ExpirationPlugin } = workbox.expiration;
const { warmStrategyCache } = workbox.recipes;
const { offlineFallback } = workbox.recipes;
const { precacheAndRoute } = workbox.precaching;


const strategy = new CacheFirst();
const urls = [
  '/offline.html'
];


warmStrategyCache({ urls, strategy });

offlineFallback();


const HTML_CACHE = "html";
const JS_CACHE = "javascript";
const STYLE_CACHE = "stylesheets";
const IMAGE_CACHE = "images";
const FONT_CACHE = "fonts";
const JSON_CACHE = "json";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});


workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /.*\.json/,
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: JSON_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 2,
      }),
    ],
  }),
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'document',
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: HTML_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 10,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'script',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: JS_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'style',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: STYLE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'image',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: IMAGE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ event }) => event.request.destination === 'font',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: FONT_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```