# XMLHttpRequest in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

How to send and recieve info from php file with XMLHttpRequest?

I try using XMLHttpRequest and jquery ajax. In both cases work find, but I can't extract the data.

**Js file**

```
var parametros = {
            "url" : url
    };

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "file.php", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

    alert(xhr.responseText)
  }
}
xhr.send(parametros);
```

**file.php**

```
  <?php 
$str = $POST['url'];
echo $str;

    ?>
```

The alert show me all the php file, with php tags (plain text).
How to recieve only the $str var?

**EDIT:** manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Get pages source",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Get pages source from a popup",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["http://localhost/extencio/*"]
}
```

Comment: You make sure you have CORS headers or send jsonp

Comment: Did you set up the manifest file?

Comment: Thanks adeneo. I do not know how to do it. I use Jsonparse with jquery ajax, but doesn't work.

Comment: You could just do what epascarello says, add permissions in your manifest instead, and you'll be able to do cross-origin requests. Here's something -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions

Comment: I'll try to pack extension adeneo.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds more like an error on webserver, are you sure your webserver is executing the php file? You could test this by going to the location of the php file with your browser.

If it also shows all of the PHP in your webbrowser, take a look at this question:
[PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: Yes the webserver execute fine the php file. I am working on more php scripts and work fine.